# PHP Multiple file upload with change of name

Tags: php

I got this code from w3 schools and it works and looks right, I am just stumped on changing the description of upload your file. 
to the first one being upload invoice.
second upload stocksheet
third upload POD
fourth upload picture.

any help will be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Basic Uploader</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>

<h2>Cases</h2>

<?php


$full_path = "c:/scott/source/";

# Set how many simultaneous uploads to allow.

$number_of_uploads = 4;

# Set allowed file types, lowercase without period (.)

$allowed_file_types =    array("jpg","gif","png","txt","zip","xls","doc","docx","xlsx");

# Change the upload_folder path, with trailing slash, 
# to your full directory path if neccessary, and set 
# permissions (chmod) to 777.

$upload_folder = "./uploads/";

# Set maximum file upload size in kilobytes.

$max_size_in_kb = 1024;

# Set 1 to rename files, 0 to keep original file names.

$rename_files = 1;

# END SETTING VARIABLES #################

function printForm()
{
global $allowed_file_types,$number_of_uploads,$max_size_in_kb;

print "<form action=\"". htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES) ."\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">\n";

    for($i=0;$i<$number_of_uploads;$i++)
    {
    print "<p><input type=\"file\" name=\"file[]\" /></p>\n";
    }

print "<p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"upload\" value=\"1\" /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload\" /></p>\n</form>\n";

print "<p>Allowed file types: ." . implode($allowed_file_types, " ."). "</p>\n";
}

$fileNAMES = array();

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    for($i=0;$i<$number_of_uploads;$i++)
    {
        if(strlen($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) > 0)
        {
        $filearray = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
        $ext = end($filearray);

            if($rename_files == 1)
            {
            list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
            $fileNAMES[$i] = $sec."_".$usec;
            }
            else
            {
            $xperiods = str_replace("." . $ext, "", $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
            $fileNAMES[$i] = str_replace(".", "", $xperiods);
            }

            if(!in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowed_file_types))
            {
            print "<p class=\"error\">FAILED: ". htmlspecialchars($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) ."<br />ERROR: File type not allowed.</p>\n";
            }
            elseif($_FILES['file']['size'][$i] > ($max_size_in_kb*1024))
            {
            print "<p class=\"error\">FAILED: ". htmlspecialchars($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) ."<br />ERROR: File size to large.</p>\n";
            }
            elseif(file_exists($upload_folder.$fileNAMES[$i] .".". $ext))
            {
            print "<p class=\"error\">FAILED: ". htmlspecialchars($fileNAMES[$i]) .".". $ext ."<br />ERROR: File already exists.</p>\n";
            }
            else
            {
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_folder.$fileNAMES[$i] .".". $ext))
                {
                print "<p>UPLOADED: ". htmlspecialchars($fileNAMES[$i]) .".". $ext ."</p>\n";
                }
                else
                {
                print "<p class=\"error\">FAILED: ". htmlspecialchars($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) ."<br />ERROR: Undetermined.</p>\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
printForm();
}
else
{
printForm();
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

in additions the file name that gets generated i would like to have a post from previous page put in front. $case_id

Regards

Comment: You just want to change the file names, right?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
     <title>Basic Uploader</title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
       </head>

      <body>

       <h2>Cases</h2>

        <?php


       $full_path = "c:/scott/source/";

        # Set how many simultaneous uploads to allow.

     $number_of_uploads = 4;

  # Set allowed file types, lowercase without period (.)

     $allowed_file_types =    array("jpg","gif","png","txt","zip","xls","doc","docx","xlsx");

   # Change the upload_folder path, with trailing slash, 
    # to your full directory path if neccessary, and set 
     # permissions (chmod) to 777.

    $upload_folder = "./uploads/";

   # Set maximum file upload size in kilobytes.

   $max_size_in_kb = 1024;

   # Set 1 to rename files, 0 to keep original file names.

   $rename_files = 1;

    # END SETTING VARIABLES #################

  function printForm()
    {
   global $allowed_file_types,$number_of_uploads,$max_size_in_kb;

   print "<form action=\"". htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES) ."\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">\n";

  for($i=0;$i<$number_of_uploads;$i++)
  {
  print "<p><input type=\"file\" name=\"file[]\" /></p>\n";
  }

 print "<p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"upload\" value=\"1\" /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload\" /></p>\n</form>\n";

   print "<p>Allowed file types: ." . implode($allowed_file_types, " ."). "</p>\n";
    }

    $fileNAMES = array();

      if(isset($_POST['upload']))
    {
     for($i=0;$i<$number_of_uploads;$i++)
       {
       if(strlen($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) > 0)
     {
     $filearray = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
    $ext = end($filearray);

        if($rename_files == 1)
        {
         if($i==0)  
         {  
          $fileNAMES[$i] = "upload invoice";
         }
         if($i==1)  
         {  
          $fileNAMES[$i] = "upload stocksheet";
         }
         if($i==2)  
         {  
          $fileNAMES[$i] = "upload POD";
         }
         if($i==3)  
         {  
          $fileNAMES[$i] = "upload picture";
         }
        }
        else
        {
        $xperiods = str_replace("." . $ext, "", $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
        $fileNAMES[$i] = str_replace(".", "", $xperiods);
        }

        if(!in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowed_file_types))
        {
        print "<p class=\"error\">FAILED: ". htmlspecialchars($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) ."<br />ERROR: File type not allowed.</p>\n";
        }
        elseif($_FILES['file']['size'][$i] > ($max_size_in_kb*1024))
        {
        print "<p class=\"error\">FAILED: ". htmlspecialchars($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) ."<br />ERROR: File size to large.</p>\n";
        }
        elseif(file_exists($upload_folder.$fileNAMES[$i] .".". $ext))
        {
        print "<p class=\"error\">FAILED: ". htmlspecialchars($fileNAMES[$i]) .".". $ext ."<br />ERROR: File already exists.</p>\n";
        }
        else
        {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_folder.$fileNAMES[$i] .".". $ext))
            {
            print "<p>UPLOADED: ". htmlspecialchars($fileNAMES[$i]) .".". $ext ."</p>\n";
            }
            else
            {
            print "<p class=\"error\">FAILED: ". htmlspecialchars($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) ."<br />ERROR: Undetermined.</p>\n";
            }
        }
    }
    }
  printForm();
   }
   else
    {
      printForm();
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: thank you - it now saves the file as pod etc. thank you thank you. just one more thing.Al four says chose file. how can i change the label of the choose file to say choose invoice etc etc.

Comment: I got the $caseid right. thanks. Now I just need to add a description to what files needs to be uploaded in stead of the choose file - should say choose invoice etc etc

Comment: Found it.    for($i=0;$i<$number_of_uploads;$i++)
  {
   if($i == '0') {
    echo "Invoice";
   }
     elseif($i == '1') {
    echo "POD";
   }